Should we venerate the Sangha or just the Noble Sangha?
As a young Buddhist, I was taught to respect members of the order and venerate the Sangha. Recently, I was told that the word Sangha only refers to the Noble Sangha (i.e. Ariya-sangha not Sammuti-sangha) in a comment.

the word Sangha refers to the Noble Sangha

My question is whether veneration should or should not be accorded by default to the Sangha (both conventional and Noble Sangha) or should it be reserved only to the Noble ones (i.e. the eight noble beings). Why and why not? (A side note: I find this answer by the ex-forumer @Yeshe Tenley to be a good read).

Does the word "venerate" have a clear, specific meaning? E.g. "be polite to and about" might be one thing, and "accept and promote the teachings of" might be another.

I refer to this definition i.e. To regard with deep respect or reverence.

The definition certainly does not apply to puthujjana monks, if they are expected by you, Desmon, to be revered with awe.

venerate Indra, leader of the ninja turtles

We should be grateful to the conventional sangha of ordained monastics because they preserved the scriptures, spread the teachings, and kept alive the tradition and practices, for over 2500 years. Without them, Buddhism would surely have vanished from the world centuries after the Buddha's passing.
However, we should emulate the ideal sangha of the eight types of noble persons, rather than the conventional sangha. Without them, we would never have examples of attaining the four stages of liberation (stream entry, once-returner, never-returner and arahant).
These are the two ways we can venerate the two types of sangha.

The word Sangha, on the external level, has two senses: conventional
and ideal. In its ideal sense, the Sangha consists of all people, lay
or ordained, who have practiced the Dhamma to the point of gaining at
least a glimpse of the Deathless. In a conventional sense, Sangha
denotes the communities of ordained monks and nuns. The two meanings
overlap but are not necessarily identical. .....
When taking refuge in the external Sangha, one takes refuge in both
senses of the Sangha, but the two senses provide different levels of
refuge. The conventional Sangha has helped keep the teaching alive for
more than 2,500 years. Without them, we would never have learned what
the Buddha taught. However, not all members of the conventional Sangha
are reliable models of behavior. So when looking for guidance in the
conduct of our lives, we must look to the living and recorded examples
provided by the ideal Sangha. Without their example, we would not know
(1) that Awakening is available to all, and not just to the Buddha;
and (2) how Awakening expresses itself in real life.
From: Refuge: An Introduction to the Buddha, Dhamma, & Sangha by Ven. Thanissaro


While there will always be disputes and differences in opinions, it is not a reason to insult, disrespect and treat other Pali scholars with contempt. Many of these Pali scholars like Venerable Thanissaro, Venerable Sujato, Venerable Bodhi and so on had made tremendous contributions in the translations of Pali texts into plain and simple English for audiences all over the world. In the process, they had spent years and even decades of their lives in selfless sacrifice for the benefit of humanity.
The fact that many of these monks are born in the West before their ordination is not a crime. They should not be treated with disdain just because of their background. For example, I recalled first reading Venerable Thanissaro’s Pali to English translation in the Access to Insight website. It was only later that a separate website was set up solely devoted to his translations. The fact that a separate website existed, focusing solely on his huge collections of works testified to the tremendous efforts as well as the long and hard dedication and sacrifices made. He and all the other Pali scholars should be treated better.
Perhaps, there are those amongst us in this forum who would like to show their chops in Pali when they correct the translations of these Pali scholars. I implore you to do so respectfully without any insinuations and disdain. The fact that many of the forum’s answers referenced the works of these scholars testify to the huge debt of gratitude that we owe to them. And not forgetting all the conveniences and benefits that we are enjoying as a result of their sweat and tears.
If you still think that you are better than them, I have a suggestion. Why don’t you put up your translations on the web. Do the same as these Pali scholars. Stick your neck out to be chop off by any would be keyboard warriors. Don’t hide behind Internet anonymity and take potshots. In fact, you can do as what Venerable Thanissaro did if you lack sufficient funding. Start by contributing your translation works for free to sites like Access to Insight. Once, you build up a loyal following then ask for donations from your fans and set up your own website.
In the Dhammapada v258, it was said:

He is not a wise man just because he talks much; only he who is peaceful, free from enmity, and does no harm to others, is to be called 'a wise man'.

Perhaps, we can keep the above in mind the next time we wish to correct these scholars. As @ruben2020 had mentioned in his answer, we should be grateful to the Sangha. Then, all the more we should venerate those amongst the Sangha who had sacrificed a huge portion of their lives in painstaking, selfless and repetitive service, asking for no return but simply for the lasting well-being and happiness of humanity.

Well said. There's no way to repay what they've given, but we can at least be thankful, and try to learn from them.

The Vinaya says false teachings cause fracture:

If, Upāli, there is one monk on one side and two on the other, and a fourth makes the proclamation and distributes ballots, saying, ‘This is the Teaching, this is the Monastic Law, this is the Teacher’s instruction; take this, approve of this,’ then this is a fracture in the Sangha, but not a schism in the Sangha.
Kd 17

Again, the Vinaya says formally acting (I guess publishing on the internet is a formal act) to misrepresent the Dhamma is incurable leading to hell.

“If he is possessed of how many qualities, revered sir, is a
schismatic in the Order doomed to the Downfall, to Niraya Hell,
staying there for an aeon, incurable?”
“If he is possessed of five qualities, Upāli, … incurable. Of what
five? As to this, Upāli, a monk explains non- dhamma as Dhamma, he
explains Dhamma as non-dhamma … non-discipline as Discipline, …
Discipline as non-discipline and he is one misrepresenting view as to
formal act. If he is possessed of these five qualities, Upāli …
incurable.
Pvr17

Importantly, for naive gullible impressionable lay devotees to themselves avoid a similar complicit descent into hell (refer to AN 10.211 about the quickest path to "hell"), SN 55.7 says they should not only engage in truthful speech but also speak in praise of truthful speech. In other words, a lay devotee of the Buddha should avoid condoning misrepresentations of the Teachings:

Reflecting in this way, they give up lying themselves. And they encourage others to give up lying, praising the giving up of lying.
SN 55.7

Similarly, MN 95 says a lay person takes faith in a monk only after investigating the mind of the monk for states of greed (worldly ambition), hatred & delusion.

Here, Bhāradvāja, a bhikkhu may be living in dependence on some
village or town. Then a householder or a householder’s son goes to him
and investigates him in regard to three kinds of states: in regard to
states based on greed, in regard to states based on hate, and in
regard to states based on delusion:... When he has investigated him
and has seen that he is purified from states based on delusion, then
he places faith in him; filled with faith he visits him and pays
respect to him; having paid respect to him, he gives ear; when he
gives ear, he hears the Dhamma.
MN 95

I recall once reading a wise (possibly Noble) layperson on a certain discussion site directly & straightforwardly telling a senior monk if the senior monk's insistent advice was followed it would be a perilous danger for the layperson's practice. This is an example of a layperson following the instructions of the Lord Buddha & shunning a Mara masquerading as a bhikkhu.
The suttas (eg MN 22, MN 38) consistently say the monk with wrong view have misrepresented us, injured yourself, and stored up much demerit; for this will lead to your harm and suffering for a long time. These monks cannot be venerated. The Buddha himself criticised & admonished these monks.

But still you misrepresent me by your wrong grasp, harm yourself, and
create much wickedness. This will be for your lasting harm and
suffering.
MN 22


But you, misguided man, by your wrong grasp have misrepresented us, injured yourself, and stored up much demerit; for this will lead to your harm and suffering for a long time.
When this was said, the bhikkhu... sat silent, dismayed, with shoulders drooping and head down, glum, and without response. Then, knowing this, the Blessed One told him: “Misguided man, you will be recognised by your own pernicious view. I shall question the bhikkhus on this matter.”
MN 22

MN 115 says:

They understand: ‘It’s impossible for a person accomplished in view to
dedicate themselves to another teacher. But it’s possible for an
ordinary person (puthujjano) to dedicate themselves to another
teacher.’

In this essay, a monk dedicates themself to Vacchagotta, imputing the ideas of Vacchagotta about "natthattā" (found only once in the suttas) onto the Buddha; as though "natthattā" means "sunnata". Despite being corrected & admonished countless times, this monk appears to cling to their wrong view and has not removed the essay from publication. This monks appears to have transgressed MN 8, which says:

Others will misapprehend according to their individual views, hold on
to them tenaciously and not easily discard them; we shall not
misapprehend according to individual views nor hold on to them
tenaciously, but shall discard them with ease — thus effacement can be
done.
MN 8

There is another monk that has never renounced their views about a permanent unconditioned consciousness; despite often been questioned about it.
There is another monk that continues to slander the very concept of Buddhahood by continually asserting the Upanishads existed during Gotama's life and was a significant influence upon the Buddha Gotama. This cannot be true because no Upanishand is mentioned in any sutta and because the concept of Buddhahood means awakening to the Truth never previously known.

In regard to things unheard before, there arose in me vision, knowledge, wisdom, true knowledge, and light.
SN 56.11


A Tathāgata awakens to that and realizes that. Having awakened to it and realized it, he announces it, teaches it, describes it, expresses it, reveals it, explains it, and clarifies it.
AN 3.136

None of these things can be venerated with a sense of awe.
In summary, it appears, today, there is not one monk, according to their teachings, who gives the impression of being an arahant. In other words, there appears to exist only Two Refuges today, namely, the Buddha and the Dhamma. The 'Sangha' refuge appears to have become extinct.
Individuals that have devoted their lives to translating are of a certain jati (birth). They serve a certain role. However, when their mistranslations are corrected by others, they should correct their translations. The fact they do not correct their translations gives the impression they are not "selfless" but, instead, appear motivated by personal, sectarian &/or worldly agendas.
The "selfless" ones are those who are subject to constant persecution for publishing Noble Right View; persecuted by those craving for rebirth & heavenly beings (heavenly selves). The suttas say those who have Noble Right View are "rare". Without these selfless ones, the Buddha-Dhamma would be completely lost, as it was for centuries, where the conventional Theravada view was not even stream-entry is possible.

Licchavis, the appearance of five treasures is rare in the world.
What five? The appearance of a Realized One, a perfected one, a fully awakened Buddha. A teacher of the teaching and training proclaimed by a Realized One. A person who understands the teaching and training proclaimed by a Realized One.
AN 5.143

The Thanissaro monk appears wrong again when he wrote:

The conventional Sangha has helped keep the teaching alive for more
than 2,500 years. Without them, we would never have learned what the
Buddha taught.

In reality, until very recently, the True Dhamma was lost for hundreds of years.

When a monk sends us harmfully on a wrong path due to the monk's faulty teachings we will know what is worthy of veneration.
When we read the Pali suttas, we find all of the monks were on the same page as the Buddha and taught the same as the Buddha. This is not the case today. Today, individual monks often provide different teachings & interpretations of Buddhism because often these monks are taught (as was done in the Ajahn Chah Western tradition) to individualize their teachings for the purpose of attracting their own genre of followers for the purpose of developing their own 'livelihood'. None of this is related to Noble Sangha, who are defined as the Sangha of the Lord Buddha's disciples.
How can the various contemporary monks be the Sangha of the Lord's Disciples (bhagavato sāvakasaṅgho) when each of them teaches a different version of Dhamma?

all of the monks were on the same page, no they were not. The story of the six infamous monks were mentioned often in the Tipitaka.

Hello. It interesting to read this identification with the rotten monks & to consider these rotten monks as "Sangha".

Gratitude to a translator does not make the translator "Noble". The reality is each translator has wrong translations and any wrong translations deems the translator to be a puthujjana. They cannot be venerated. The suttas (eg MN 22, MN 38) consistently say the monk with wrong view have misrepresented us, injured yourself, and stored up much demerit; for this will lead to your harm and suffering for a long time.”
